# Inner product evaluation in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, definition, mathematics, linear-algebra

On wikipedia on the page for inner product it states that for any two $x,y$ in a vector space $V$ the inner product $(\cdot , \cdot)$ satisfies $(ax, y) = a(x,y)$ where $a\in\mathbb{C}$.

The inner product of the kets $|\psi\rangle, |\phi\rangle$ in a Hillbert space $\mathcal{H}$ is denoted by $\langle \phi|\psi\rangle = (|\psi\rangle, |\phi\rangle)$. However, this means that $(a|\psi\rangle, |\phi\rangle) = (a|\psi\rangle)^\dagger|\phi\rangle = a^*\langle \psi|\phi\rangle$.

I'm a little confused as to how this makes sense.

Comment: This is solely a matter of convention: Check what the Wikipedia article says about scalars in the second argument of the inner product...

Comment: thanks, I guess I should have looked a bit further

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesquilinear_form#Convention